# Is there a reliable way to know when a message is successfully acknowledged?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a spring boot app that uses Spring AMQP. The AMQP config is like this

```
@Configuration
public class AmqpConfig {
  @Bean
  DirectExchange directExchange() { return new DirectExchange("amq.direct"); }

  @Bean
  Queue testQueue() { return QueueBuilder.durable("test").build(); }

  @Bean
  Binding testBinding(Queue testQueue, DirectExchange directExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(testQueue).to(directExchange).with("test.routing.key");
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory manualContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                     SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(containerFactory, connectionFactory);
    containerFactory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return containerFactory;
  }
}
```

So I'm using MANUAL acknowledgements. There's one listener

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ManualListener {
  @RabbitListener(queues = "test", containerFactory = "manualContainerFactory")
  public void processMsg(Message message, Channel channel, @Header(DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
    try {
      log.info("Message received");
      Thread.sleep(20000);
      channel.basicAck(tag, false);
      log.info("Message processed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Something went wrong: {}", message, e);
      channel.basicNack(tag, false, false);
    }
  }
}
```

`Thread.sleep(20000)` is here to simulate some time-consuming process. My test case is:

1. Send a message to the listener above
2. During the 20 seconds sleep, restart rabbitmq. This effectively terminates all channels on the queue

So, what I expected to happen in this case is `channel.basicAck` to throw an exception that channel is closed, so that I can act accordingly (revert previous actions or similar). What actually happens is that `basicAck` finishes like everything is ok and `CachingConnectionFactory` just logs an exception in the background that PRECONDITION_FAILED for delivery.

```
2017-12-15 11:00:47.627  INFO 39397 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] .ManualListener : Message processed
2017-12-15 11:00:47.628 ERROR 39397 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] nnectionFactory : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
```

My question is: is there a reliably way for `@RabbitListener` to know when a message is successfully acknowledged?

Spring-boot: 1.5.2.RELEASE, Spring-rabbit: 1.7.1.RELEASE

**EDIT:**

I tried solution with `((ChannelProxy) channel).getTargetChannel()` proposed by Gary Russell. It looks like it only mitigates the problem, there are still some messages that are falsely acked. I created this test, which I think it proves this.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ManualListener {
  static int counter = 0;

  @RabbitListener(queues = "test", containerFactory = "manualContainerFactory")
  public void processMsg(Message message, Channel channel, @Header(DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
      log.info("Message received with delivery tag {} and redelivered {}", message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), message.getMessageProperties().getRedelivered());
      if (!message.getMessageProperties().getRedelivered()) {
        new Thread(() -> {
          try {
            channel.getConnection().close();
            log.info("Connection closed");
          } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Connection closed with timeout", e);
          }
        }).start();
      }
      new Thread(() -> {
        Channel actualChannel = ((ChannelProxy) channel).getTargetChannel();
        try {
          actualChannel.basicAck(tag, false);
          log.info("Number of acknowledged messages: {}", ++counter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Something went wrong: {}", message, e);
        }
      }).start();
  }
}
```

What I can see in the logs is:

```
2018-01-10 13:17:34.133  INFO 17250 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] .ManualListener : Message received with delivery tag 1 and redelivered false
2018-01-10 13:17:34.137  INFO 17250 --- [      Thread-27] .ManualListener : Number of acknowledged messages: 1
2018-01-10 13:17:34.163  INFO 17250 --- [      Thread-26] .ManualListener : Connection closed
2018-01-10 13:17:35.162  INFO 17250 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] .ManualListener : Message received with delivery tag 1 and redelivered true
2018-01-10 13:17:35.162  INFO 17250 --- [      Thread-28] .ManualListener : Number of acknowledged messages: 2
```

So in the test I acked the same message twice. What I would expect in this case to happen is to receive `IOException` when `basicAck` is called.

This problem occurs in our production environment, the app process large volumes of messages and acks quite often. Every time the connection is dropped, a couple of already acked messages is received.

Answer (score 2):

The channel proxy recovers (refreshes) the underlying rabbitmq channel when it is detected closed.

You could call `isOpen()`, but there is still a small race condition between that call and your `basicAck()`.

**EDIT**

You could also add a shut down listener...

```
channel.addShutdownListener(s -> {
    System.out.println(s);
});
channel.basicAck(tag, false);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a reliable work-around...

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
public void foo(Message m, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
        @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long tag) throws Exception {
    System.in.read();
    Channel actualChannel = ((ChannelProxy) channel).getTargetChannel();
    try {
        actualChannel.basicAck(tag, false);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:253)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:422)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:416)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicAck(ChannelN.java:1164)
    at com.example.So47454769Application.foo(So47454769Application.java:42)
```

Comment: I tried the solution above. There are still some falsely acked messages. I edited my question with additional info.

Comment: This has been [fixed on master - AMQP-793](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-793) - we need to scheduled a 2.0.2 release to include the fix; you could try 2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT to verify if you want.